# MissingMethodException: No signature of method error after replacing method using groovy metaclass?

Tags: grails, groovy

I have a simple domain

```
class Cat {

    String name

    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

The controller is as follows:

```
class CatController {

    def index() { }


    def say(){


        def cat = new Cat(name: "cc")
        cat.save()

        render "done"   

    }
}
```

and i have a test integration test as follows:

```
class CatTests  extends GroovyTestCase{

    CatController controller = new CatController()

    @Test
    void testSomething() {


        Cat.metaClass.save = {

            throw new Exception("Asdasd")
        }

        shouldFail(Exception){

                controller.say()

        }


        GroovySystem.metaClassRegistry.removeMetaClass(Cat.class)


    }


    @Test
    void testSomething2() {

        def before_cat_count = Cat.count()

        controller.say()

        def after_cat_count = Cat.count()

        assertEquals after_cat_count - before_cat_count, 1


    }


}
```

I get the following error when running the test.

```
Failure:  testSomething2(cat.CatTests)
|  groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: cat.Cat.count() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: count(), ident(), print(java.lang.Object), print(java.io.PrintWriter), getCount(), wait()
    at cat.CatTests.testSomething2(CatTests.groovy:37)
| Completed 2 integration tests, 1 failed in 192ms
```

Now, my doubt and question is why is it not finding the count method on this line

```
def before_cat_count = Cat.count()
```

of testSomething2() method.

I have already removed the meta class at the end of method testSomething. So, i am wondering why is count() method not being found. I appreciate any help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps simply

GroovySystem.metaClassRegistry.removeMetaClass(Cat)

simply Cat, not Cat.class

Sourced from the web, I use a method for this type of cleanup.

```
def revokeMetaClassChanges(Class type, def instance = null) {
    GroovySystem.metaClassRegistry.removeMetaClass(type)
    if(instance) {
        instance.metaClass = null
    }
}
```

With invocations like:

```
cleanup:
    revokeMetaClassChanges(FirstService, firstServiceInstance)
    revokeMetaClassChanges(SecondService, null)
```

with much success.

Comment: sorry i just used Cat instead of Cat.class for removeMetaClass parameter but that didn't work.

Comment: In Groovy, a class name can be used in place of the static .class reference. That is, Cat and Cat.class are equivalent.